# TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable when practicing list-comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Im having a problem using for-loops in combination with an if statement in lists in python. Im receiving the error "TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable" when I try to execute the following code:

```
lista = ["Hello", "And", "Goodbye"]

uppgift = [s + "..." for s in lista if (s.lower() in lista.__contains__("h") or s.lower() in lista.__contains__(
    "o") or s.lower() in lista.__contains__("a"))]

print(uppgift)
```

Do you know how to solve this? Im currently at the learning stage of python so the following code is me trying to understand the limitations of python.

I do not know how to take execution from the TypeError. From my understanding it is the if-statement that has some problem to iterate for every value in the list "lista". I do not know how to take action from this.

Comment: `s.lower() in lista.__contains__("h")`——What is this supposed to mean? `lista.__contains__("h")` is either true or false, so how could `s.lower()` be _in_ it?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I solved it. You got a point there, a boolean cannot be the same thing as a string value. :')

Comment: `__contains__` isn't meant to be called as you do it. That's what `in` is for. If you define an own class you can overwrite the `__contains__` method to define the behaviour if you use `in` with an instance of that class. The same applies to all methods with double leading and trailing underscores.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I probably overcomplicated it. It worked by doing this:

`lista = ["Hello", "And", "Goodbye"]

uppgift = [s.lower() + "..." for s in lista if ("h" in s or "o" in s or "a" in s)]

print(uppgift)`